# Modify permissions for scripts recursively

Tags: unix, chmod

Trying to set permissions recursively for multiple scripts:

```
chmod -R /export/home/*.sh
```

But some files do not have `.sh` extension, e.g. `.ksh` and some scripts have **no extension at all**.

How can I make all scripts/files executable? (any type, extension or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should do the trick:

```
find /export/home -type f -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

However, I don't think you really want to make all files executable - there is significant security risk in this.  You'd be better off just determining what files should be executable, or putting them in a "bin/" subdirectory, which you could then search for:

```
find /export/home -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R +x {} \;
```